# "message": "Network Error", "name": "AxiosError",

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, express, axios

I have used a full project with concurrent using vuejs and calling an api request using axios post request my request is

`axios({`
`method: "POST",`
`url: http://abcd.com:5000/start-recording?roomId=${this.roomId},`
`headers: {`
`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`
`},`
`})`
`.then(function (response) {`
`console.log(response)`
`})`
`.catch(function (error) {`
`console.log(error)`
`});`

but it gives me a network error as below

`{`
`"message": "Network Error",`
`"name": "AxiosError",`
`"config": {`
`"transitional": {`
`"silentJSONParsing": true,`
`"forcedJSONParsing": true,`
`"clarifyTimeoutError": false`
`},`
`"transformRequest": [`
`null`
`],`
`"transformResponse": [`
`null`
`],`
`"timeout": 0,`
`"xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",`
`"xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",`
`"maxContentLength": -1,`
`"maxBodyLength": -1,`
`"env": {`
`"FormData": null`
`},`
`"headers": {`
`"Accept": "application/json, text/plain,` *`/`*`",`
`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"`
`},`
`"method": "post",`
``` "url": "``http://abcd.com:5000/start-recording?roomId=3503``" ```
`},`
`"code": "ERR_NETWORK",`
`"status": null`
`}`

i was trying to resolve this issue through out the day please if someone could help it would be a great help

Thank you in Advance

Note - this issue is not occuring in local but when we use it in server this happens and when i call the api through the postman it works

I was accepting a response that recording started

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue occurs because you are not sending a body with your `POST` request. Because of this the `Content-Type` is set to something else than `application/json` which the server only accepts so it throws back an error to you. I think sending an empty object in the body will fix it. You can also set the `header` in your request to contain `Content-Type: application/json`.
I think why it only happens on server and not on local is because your webserver is changing the request before sending it by appending `Content-Type` to it.

Comment: I tried this way but same error continues

Comment: hmmmm weird, a way to debug this would be to send a request to a place where you can receive it and see what it sends and see the difference between when sending it from local and from the server. I did a quick google search for something you can use for free to receive and view request and found this site to do it https://webhook.site/

Comment: i get the same error + cors error

Comment: But do you see your response on webhook? and if yes how does it differ the request you are getting from local

Comment: i saw the response

Comment: OPTIONS https://webhook.site/e05d4445-2997-4348-844d-0d77db34590e
Host abcd
Date 03/07/2023 3:59:44 PM (4 minutes ago)
Size 0 bytes
ID ead99be6-a54b-4f91-bb6f-a0baf12589a9
Files
Headers
connection close
accept-language en-US,en;q=0.9
accept-encoding gzip, deflate, br
referer https://ipg.drivingqatar.com:8181/
sec-fetch-dest empty
sec-fetch-site cross-site
sec-fetch-mode cors
user-agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
origin https://abcd.com:8181

Comment: What kind of server are you running on? And then i mean webserver to serve the HTML to the user are you using `apache`, `nginx`, `etc`